# How can I calculate the variance if the only thing I know is the difference between the random variables?

Tags: statistics

If I know $\alpha=x_2-x_1$ and $\beta=(x_3-x_1)+(x_3-x_2)$, how can I calculate the variance of $\{x_1,x_2, x_3\}$?

Comment: Hint:  Adding a constant to all three numbers does not change the variance, so you may assume the mean is $0$. Now easy to solve for the three variables.

Answer (score 1):

$x_3-x_2=(x_3-x_1)-(x_2-x_1)$ allows you to easily obtain $x_k-x_1$. The shift by $x_1$ doesn't change the variance.